# VBScript How to prevent form submission after user hits back button?

Tags: forms, vbscript

I have an HTML form whose fields get inserted into a database. If I submit the form successfully, then click a link to another page, and then hit the Back button, it will resubmit the same data into the database.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: This happens due to the way a browser works, you can work around that by using ajax to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Form Submission page you can check which page it has come from through javascript, based on that data in forms submit validation you can either allow or restrict the form submission and that will help you to prevent form submission if the form is requested from a different page other than intended